# Using cmake to output a bin directory

Tags: python, cmake, bin, pdf2image, poppler-utils

I'm looking to use `pdf2image` to convert pdfs to images, and I'm having a bit of trouble getting `poppler-utils` to function with that library. I was informed I'd need to use `cmake` in order to generate the `bin` folder and place that folder in the path, but I'm not sure how I'd use `cmake` to do that. Would anyone be able to provide some guidance on how that would work?